# Does a contractible locally connected continuum have an fixed point property?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I'm surprised that I can't find any research on this topic. Maybe it's too obvious? Kinoshita proved that [contractible continuum do not have FPP](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm40/fm4019.pdf), but his example is not locally connected. Maybe if we add this to the conditions it will have FPP?

UPD: [Continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(topology)) as a nonempty compact connected metric space

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CrSb0001 How can i impove it? I'm asking for answer yes or not with maybe some links on research in this topic. Question 
"Does a contractible locally connected continuum have an fixed point property?" 
not clear?

Comment: The function $f(x)=x+1$ on $\Bbb{R}$ does not have a fixed point.  Does that answer the question?

Comment: @JohnDoe No. I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(topology) continuum as nonempty compact connected metric space. Thank you. I'll add it to question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I do not have an answer to your question, here are two related results:

1. If $X$ is a 1-dimensional contractible continuum, then $X$ satisfies the FPP (every continuous self-map $X\to X$ has a fixed point). See:

*Young, G. S.*, [**Fixed-point theorems for arcwise connected continua**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2034430), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 11, 880-884 (1961). [ZBL0102.37806](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0102.37806).

2. Suppose that $X$ is an acyclic compact ANR. Then $X$ satisfies the FPP. See Corollary 8.10 on page 68 in

*Górniewicz, L.*, On the Lefschetz fixed point theorem, Brown, R.F. (ed.) et al., Handbook of topological fixed point theory. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 1-4020-3221-8/hbk). 43-82 (2005). [ZBL1077.55001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1077.55001).

In order to connect to your question, note that every ANR is locally contractible and *almost conversely* every finite dimensional metrizable locally contractible space is an ANR.

My guess is that one should assume in your question local contractibility instead of local connectivity, but I do not have an example.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't understand how to connect these results, because there is no acyclic condition. About local properties, i meant local connectivity, because Kinoshita's example of contractible continua was not localy connected. Please don't mark this answer as solve, maybe someone have more information to share.

Comment: @LoliDeveloper: Did you take any algebraic topology classes? Acyclic is weaker than contractible.

Comment: Oh, sure, my bad. Kinda beginner in this area

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the Cone over Hawaiian ring is not an ANR? But still satisfies the assumptions

Comment: It is not locally simply connected, hence, not an ANR. Of course, ANR is stronger than local connectivity.

Comment: @LoliDeveloper: By the way, only you can accept an answer to your questions, by clicking the checkmark next to an answer. Since no true answer has emerged so far (after 10 days), my suggestion is to ask at MathOverflow, but refer to this question at Math Stack Exchange as a cross-post. It is a good question.

Comment: Thank you, I hope I [did that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448657/does-a-contractible-locally-connected-continuum-have-an-fixed-point-property) right